# How to check if dynamically adding options to select box is completed?

Tags: javascript

I have a select box.

```
<select id="some_id">
</select>
```

I load options from server after an event.

I just want to run some callbacks after options are loaded.

Problem is that I only can add user script to site not complete access.

Please suggest me an event handler process.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the callback function? After all, that's what callbacks are for

Comment: `MutationObserver`

Comment: @JeremyThille then i can set value for next select box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises. You can find out the basics of them here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises.

You would put your event into the promise and once it completes resolve it. You can then run whatever functions you would like done after the options are loaded in the promises then block. Here's some example promise code from the docs. In this the console.log("Promise callback (.then)"); runs after  the first promise resolves.

```
const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log("Promise callback");
  resolve();
}).then(function(result) {
  console.log("Promise callback (.then)");
});

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("event-loop cycle: Promise (fulfilled)", promise)
}, 0);

console.log("Promise (pending)", promise);
```